# Delete all the ads in Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, ads

I want to close all the ads that appears in the webpage one by one. The ads can appear in different places, two or one in one row. 
I have tryed to write `driver.findelement(By.xpath("//div[@id='cbb']")).click()`but the problem is that all the ads have the same code for the close button. 
Is there another way to do it?

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you use Selenium for web scraping? Can you install an adblocker in the browser?

Comment: i have installed adblock on my normal Chrome. In the new page that is open doesn't apper any of my extensions. If i would had adblocker i wouldn't ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option #1**

I would suggest using [JavascriptExecutor](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html). You can basically add `style='visibility: hidden;'` to the HTML block (ad's HTML in your case):

```
public void hideElement(String xpath)
{
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));       
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].style.visibility='hidden'", element);
}
```

For hiding multiple elements, you would need to come up with JS function, that will hide elements and then pass it **as string**  to the `executeScript()`

```
public void hideElements()
{

String jscode = "var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('className');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
        elements[i].style.display = 'none';
    };";   

// escaping single / double quotes / tabs / line breaks / so on
jscode =  escapeJS(jscode);   

    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(jscode);
}
```

helper function (needs this import: `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;` - you can get this library from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.0)):

```
/**
 * Escapes JS.
 */
public static String escapeJS(String value) {
    return StringEscapeUtils.escapeEcmaScript(value);
}
```

NOTE, make sure add necessary timeouts to wait for all ads to be loaded on the page before trying to hide them

**Option #2 - a bit hardcore if you don't have jQuery on your page**

- IF you don't have jQuery - you can add it to DOM (that will require some Java code to be added) and then use its methods to hide elements within Java code that I posted above
- IF you have jQuery loaded on your page - just search for jQuery codes to hide HTML on the page (alternative to vanilla JS I posted above) and add those codes to Java function.